# is WriteFile working ? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, serial-port

I have to send 6 byte to a device in serial port. The port is open but the data isnt sent. I use serial port monitor to know what happen with my code(C++ Win32, Visual Studio).

I am using CreateFile

```
hPort = CreateFile( TEXT("COM3"),               
                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                  0,                            
                  NULL,                         
                  OPEN_EXISTING,                
                  0,                            
                  NULL );
```

My code to write is:

```
void uart::write(char data) {

WriteFile(hPort,
    (LPCVOID)data,
    1,
    &byteswritten,
    NULL);
}
```

When i need execute a command in my device i call fuction sendCommand("000000010000000100000000000000000000000000000000");

```
void device::sendCommand(std::string command) {

int   size = command.length();
char* string = (char*)command.c_str();
std::vector<char> data(command.begin(), command.end()) ;

std::cout <<"[Uart.write]>>\n";                                             
int j=0;                                                                        
for (int k = 0; k <= size - 1; k++) {
    Uart.write(data[k]);
    std::cout << data[k];                                                       
    j++;
    if (j % 8 == 0 && j!=0) { std::cout << "__byte " << j / 8 << "send___\n";
}
```

I use the next code like as model to write the above code win32 c++.

```
       #using <System.dll>
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::IO::Ports;
    using namespace System::Threading;

    void SendCommand(SerialPort^ port, Byte unit, Byte command, Int32 data);
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SerialPort^ port;
    Byte unit;
    Byte command;
    Int32 data;

    // Set up serial port
    port = gcnew SerialPort();
    port->PortName = "COM8";
    port->BaudRate = 9600;
    port->DataBits = 8;
    port->Parity   = Parity::None;
    port->StopBits = StopBits::One;
    port->Handshake = Handshake::None;

    // Open port
    port->Open();

    // Home device 1
    SendCommand(port, 1, CMD_HOME, 0);
    WaitForReply(port, 1, CMD_HOME, unit, command, data);
// Close port
    port->Close();

    return 0;
}
    void SendCommand(SerialPort^ port, Byte unit, Byte command, Int32 data)
    {
        array<Byte>^ packet = gcnew array<Byte>(6);
    gcnew array<Byte>
        packet[0] = unit;
        packet[1] = command;

        packet[2] = data & 0xFF;
        packet[3] = (data >>  8) & 0xFF;
        packet[4] = (data >> 16) & 0xFF;
        packet[5] = (data >> 24) & 0xFF;

        port->Write(packet, 0, 6);
    }
```

I would like find something like `array<Byte>^ packet = gcnew array<Byte>(6);
        gcnew array<Byte>
            packet[0] = unit; ..........` in C++. I think my problem is that.

Comment: You decided to discard all return values. Life's too short to guess what the issue is, with zero information down.

Comment: `(LPCVOID)data,` - this is error of course (access violation) need `WriteFile(hPort,
    &data,
    sizeof(data),
    &byteswritten,
    NULL);`

Comment: @IInspectable, what kind of information do you need? I told all i thought was necessary.

Comment: @RbMm Thanks! I'll try.

Comment: [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) has several return values. You are ignoring all of them, and withhold that information from readers of your question as well.

Comment: It looks very much as though you decided to ignore the details to be found in the documentation. Why did you decide to do that?

Comment: @IInspectable i dont know how to get the values returned from writeFile. 
I will edit my post to add all code used to connect the port.

Comment: Hello @DavidHeffernan. I apologise, what documentation do you refer ? I didnt say before, im learning c++ and i dont know some concepts about lenguage. I have been reading about serial port communication but is obviously that i don't understand all.

Comment: This strikes me as odd. I linked to documentation that explains how to do that. Is clicking a hyperlink really asking too much?

Comment: You decided to call a number of Win32 API calls, and you don't appear to have read the documentation. Had you done so you would have come across the parts that discuss error handling.

Comment: @IInspectable. Im sorry. I did not realize that it was there! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void uart::write(char data) {

WriteFile(hPort,
    (LPCVOID)data,
    1,
    &byteswritten,
    NULL);
}
```

are you understand what you doing here ? you pass buffer address in range 0-255 which is of course invalid and not point to your actual data. when kernel check your buffer - exception `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` raised , which converted to `ERROR_NOACCESS` by win32. this error code must return `GetlastError()` after your call to `WriteFile` return `false`.

you need next function for write 1 byte:

```
DWORD uart::write(char data) {

DWORD byteswritten;
return WriteFile(hPort,
    &data,
    sizeof(data),
    &byteswritten,
    NULL) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}
```

not sure are after this all will be worked (are no another errors in code) but this fix is must be done

Comment: Thanks you a lot for time you expend to help me.

Comment: I have been reading about serial port, but i dont know what is writefile doing when a pass a char. At first WriteFile  use an argument CString and i decided change it becouse my device use a binary protocol and i thought CString doesnt send the right data values. 

About STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION and ERROR_NOACCESS were never shown to me. Reading comments I am sure i need some functions to know whats happen. Where can i read about these ?

Comment: @Th3venin - `WriteFile` always take a *pointer* to some buffer (and buffer size). you can not `pass a char` to it. you can pass *pointer* to char only. are you call `GetLastError` after write file ?

Comment: Thank you @RbMm ! My program is working with these changes.


  void uart::write(BYTE data){
  WriteFile( hPort,
       &data,
       1,         
       &byteswritten,
       NULL);
}


BYTE home[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){ uart.write(home[i]); }

 Thank you a lot!